# Extract packets with newline delimiter

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I have below file say "Main.cap" in unix-

If i want to capture all packets from particular IP say : 1.1.1.1 provided **all packets are not of same size**

```
Device:A
Host:B
IP:0.0.0.0
Time:123654
Location:India


Device:B
Host:C
IP:1.1.1.1
Time:125423


Device:C
Host:D
IP:1.1.1.1
Time:129423


Device:E
Host:F
IP:1.1.1.1
Time:125423
Location:Germany

Device:G
Host:H
IP:1.2.5.6
Time:12543
```

Output required of the above file is as below-

```
Device:B
Host:C
IP:1.1.1.1
Time:125423


Device:C
Host:D
IP:1.1.1.1
Time:129423


Device:E
Host:F
IP:1.1.1.1
Time:125423
Location:Germany
```

I am trying Awk RS option.

Comment: @Ploutox I want output as all packets of IP:1.1.1.1 which means 3 packets with Device:B,C and E of size 4,4 and 5 lines respectively

Comment: [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24862450/edit) your answer and add the output of for your data sample if you run a querry with IP 1.1.1.1

Comment: I am trying to use RS option in awk but exact output is missing. output i want is-`Device:B
Host:C
IP:1.1.1.1
Time:125423


Device:C
Host:D
IP:1.1.1.1
Time:129423


Device:E
Host:F
IP:1.1.1.1
Time:125423
Location:Germany`

Answer (score 3):

Using `gawk`:

```
gawk 'BEGIN{ORS="\n\n";RS=""}/.*^IP:1\.1\.1\.1$.*/' file
```

Or anything `awk`:

```
awk -v ip=1.1.1.1 'BEGIN { ORS="\n\n"; RS = ""; FS = "\n" } { for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) if ($i == "IP:" ip) { print; next } }' file
```

Output:

```
Device:B
Host:C
IP:1.1.1.1
Time:125423

Device:C
Host:D
IP:1.1.1.1
Time:129423

Device:E
Host:F
IP:1.1.1.1
Time:125423
Location:Germany
```

Comment: You do not need to include what is before or after pattern to get a match, so this `/.*IP:1\.1\.1\.1.*/` could be just `/IP:1\.1\.1\.1/`

Comment: @Jotne My original pattern was actually `/.*^IP:1\.1\.1\.1$.*/` which is more accurate but is only applicable to GNU awk.

Comment: +1 for the GNU awk solution, but your POSIX `awk` solution is a bit complicated. Didn't know that in GNU awk `^` and `$` anchor the start and end of _lines_ in multi-line records (whereas `\\` ` and `\'` match the endpoints of the _entire_ record / buffer); The slightly curious thing is that the behavior of `^` / `$` depends on whether they're at the very beginning / end of the _regex_: if they are, they anchor the entire record / buffer; otherwise, a single line.

Answer (score 1):

**[@konsolebox's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24862602/45375) contains an elegant GNU `awk` (`gawk`) solution**; it only requires a simple tweak to make it a **POSIX-compliant solution**:

```
awk -v RS='' -v ORS='\n\n' '/\nIP:1\.1\.1\.1\n/' file
```

With the IP address passed as a variable:

```
awk -v RS='' -v ORS='\n\n' -v ip='1.1.1.1' '$0 ~ "\nIP:"ip"\n"' file
```

Note that setting `RS` (the input record separator) to an empty string is an `awk` idiom that breaks the input into records by empty lines, so that each record contains a run of *consecutive nonempty lines*.